# Force size aesthetic to scale to given breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating several plots in order to create frames for a gif. It is supposed to show growing points over time. (see plot 1 and 2 - the values increase). Using size aesthetic is problematic, because the scaling is done for each plot individually.
I tried to set breaks with `scale_size_area()` to provide a sequence of absolute values, in order to scale on 'all values' rather than only the values present in each plot. (no success).

*Plot 3* shows how the points should be scaled, but this scaling should be achieved in each plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = 1:5, size2 = 21:25) 
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, size = y))   +
  geom_point() +
scale_size_area(breaks = seq(0,25,1))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, size = size2))   +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_area(breaks = seq(0,25,1))
```

[image]

```r
df2 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = 1:5, size2 = 21:25) %>% gather(key, value, y:size2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x, value, size = value))   +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_area(breaks = seq(0,25,1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass lower and upper bound to `limits` argument in `scale_size_area` function:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, size = y))   +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    title = "Y on y-axis",
    size = NULL
  ) +
  scale_size_area(limits = c(0, 25))

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, size = size2 ))   +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    title = "size2 on y-axis",
    size = NULL
  ) +
  scale_size_area(limits = c(0, 25))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library("ggplot2")
df1 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5],
                  y = 1:5) 
ggplot(data = df1, 
       aes(x = x, 
           y = y, 
           size = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_area(breaks = seq(1,25,1),
                  limits = c(1, 25))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid @PoGibas was faster with his reply